# Ambiguous IQueryable<T>.Where and IEnumerable<T>.Where on extension method

Tags: c#, linq, generics, entity-framework-6, extension-methods

I'm trying to override all Where() methods for my entities with the following extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    throw new SecurityException("Use the security SafeWhere method");
}
```

But when I use **context.EntitiesX.Where()** I'm getting the error: **The call is ambiguous between Queryable<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource,bool>>) and Enumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource,bool>>)**

How can I fix that? Also I would like that extension method to only affect entities that implements certain interface, I have tried that by specify the interface type instead of generic **T** but that's not working.

Comment: one way to fix is to not write it as extension method. write it as static method like this `YourClass.Where(context.EntitiesX , ....)`

Comment: I would like to be sure that nowhere else the base Where is being used

Comment: You can't override extensions methods. To the compiler they are exactly the same as static methods, which will result in an ambiguity when you have two methods with the same signature.

Comment: but in `Enumerable` class not override with `Expression` params

Comment: What is the namespace of the class that contains the extension method? I guess it's different than your entity namespace and you include something like `using MyExtensions` in your entity code files?

Comment: What's the purpose of redirecting the `Where` extension method?  If it's only for your entities why not give it a different name and remove the confusion altogether?

Comment: "I would like to be sure that nowhere else the base Where is being used" You can't prevent that - there's nothing that you can do to stop someone from using the `Queryable` extension method.

Comment: @DStanley you could remove the reference to System.Core.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to give your extension method higher priority than the 3rd party (system) ones.

Assuming your code structure is something like this

**MyExtensions.cs**

```
using System;
// ... other 3rd party usings

namespace MyExtensionsNamespace
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            throw new SecurityException("Use the security SafeWhere method");
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

**MyEntity.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
// ... other 3rd party usings
using MyExtensionsNamespace;

namespace MyEntitiesNamespace
{
    // ...
}
```

All you need is to move your namespace usings right after your namespace declaration like this

**MyEntity.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
// ... other 3rd party usings

namespace MyEntitiesNamespace
{
    using MyExtensionsNamespace;
    // ...
}
```

P.S. The compiler error message is misleading. It's generated when extension method syntax is used. For LINQ syntax, the error is different

> Error  CS1940  Multiple implementations of the query pattern were found for source type 'DbSet'.  Ambiguous call to 'Where'.

Comment: Enumerable class have not `Where` method with this parameter `Expression<Func<TSource,bool>>`, so seems problem not with namespaces

Comment: @Grundy I've duplicated it, and the namespace indeed is resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

> Also I would like that extension method to only affect entities that implements certain interface,

Try putting a generic constraint on your extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    where T : IMyInterface
{
    throw new SecurityException("Use the security SafeWhere method");
}
```

Although I *still* think you should choose a different name to avoid any confusion for someone else reading your code.

Comment: Putting a generic constraint does not resolve the issue, because generic constraints are not taken into account when resolving the best overload. I think Eric Lippert had a post about that. The only way is to make your class "closer".

Comment: @IvanStoev That's not the part of the problem I was addressing, and why I suggest changing the name.  A generic constraint _will_ solve the requirement of being available only to members that implement a certain interface.

Comment: I apologize, I thought you are addressing the the whole issue (which now I see you certainly didn't).